# mb_detect_encoding detects ASCII as UTF-8?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, ascii, multibyte

I'm trying to automatically convert imported IPTC metadata from images to UTF-8 for storage in a database based on the PHP `mb_` functions.

Currently it looks like this:

```
$val = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($val));
```

However, when `mb_detect_encoding()` is supplied an ASCII string (special characters in the Latin1-fields from 192-255) it detects it as UTF-8, hence in the following attempt to convert everything to proper UTF-8 all special characters are removed.

I tried writing my own method by looking for Latin1 values and if none occured I would go on to letting `mb_detect_encoding` decide what it is. But I stopped midway when I realized that I can't be sure that other encoding don't use the same byte values for other things.

So, is there a way to properly detect ASCII to feed to `mb_convert_encoding` as the source encoding?

Comment: Given a string is only possible to say for sure if it not belongs to a particular encoding. mb_detect_encoding function will examine your string and attempt to "guess" what its encoding is.

Comment: So what is it? ASCII or Latin-1? It can't be both. Also, is the encoding variable, or do you *know* the encoding? Can you maybe *get* the encoding from some meta data? "Detecting" encodings (read: best guessing them) is never a good idea; encodings need to be *specified*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specifying a custom order, where ASCII is detected first, works.

```
mb_detect_encoding($val, 'ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15');
```

For completeness, the list of available encodings is at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: Just want to add that ASCII is always valid UTF-8 (but not the other way around). And keep in mind that ASCII is not Latin1 (ISO-8859-1)!

Answer (score 2):

You can specified explicitly

```
$val = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
```

EDIT:

```
$val = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work if I could be sure of what I was importing which I cannot. Hence all the detecting...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to worry about what encodings you will allow, you can add them all

`$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($val, implode(',', mb_list_encodings()));`

Comment: I could, but `mb_list_encodings()` does not enable me to control the order in which encodings are listed.